# How to fill a region with transparency in windows forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics

I have developed a .NET Windows Forms application to Fill color on an image (Eg: map).
I have to highlight each region in a different color. I am facing problem to fill a region with a color that will be transparent enough to display the name of the region (state).
I am able to fill the region with a color but not in a transparent way. 
Please help me to fill a region in transparent way so that the background text is visible.
Thanks in advance….
Sree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a semi-transparent brush, try [this solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s2dwfx1.aspx).

Basically if you use:

```
Color.FromArgb(0...255, r, g, b)
```

The first parameter is the alpha component. Valid values are 0 through 255, where 0 means fully transparent, 255 fully opaque.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the color transparancy by the Alpha chanel of the color.

```
Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue)
```